# Определение размера шрифта по ширине символа

Tags: шрифты, java

Как можно выбрать такой размер шрифта, ширина символа которого не превышала бы указанное значение? Шрифт моноширинный.

---

UPD:
 1. Используется Swing.
 2. Собственно, так и делаю, но преподавателю не нравится.

Comment: 1. Каким графическим фреймворком барин пользоваться изволит?
2. Лучше метода последовательных приближений вам не найти. Размер шрифта не отображается на ширину символа. Так что возьмите размер `X`, измерьте строку, в зависимости от результат уменьшите или увеличьте `X`, повторять до победного конца.

Comment: @worialhat: Не нравится? А он программист? Скажите ему, что API делать напрямую нет, так что без поиска не обойтись. Для увеличения эффективности можно сделать двоичный или ещё лучше [интерполирующий](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA) поиск.

---
Кстати, а шрифт задан заранее? Если да, можно и измерить заранее ширину символа во всех размерах и вписать в программу константы. Но это может не сработать, если на другой машине шрифт хоть чуть-чуть отличается.